# Parsing XML with values containing angle brackets, using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to use Linq to parse a fragment of XML, which is stored in a string.  Here is the XML:

```
<rule name="U.S. Financial: PCI">
  <keyValues>
    <keyValue key="id" value="3421c776-c95f-4ed2-915b-a684b97ae06b" />
    <keyValue key="minCount" value="1" />
  </keyValues>
</rule>
```

When I try parsing the XML, I get an error from the whitespaces in the name attribute of the `<rule>` element.  My code for parsing is the following:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<wrapper>" + xml + "</wrapper>", LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
```

But I get the same error without the LoadOption.  The exact error is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll.  Additional information: 'U.S.' is an unexpected token. Expecting white space. Line 1, position 24.

How can I parse attributes like this which contain whitespace using Linq, and is there any reason why I have to surround the xml with the "wrapper" elements to make it work?

**EDIT:** After investigating further, I think the error is actually caused by Linq finding something it doesn't know how to parse before the closing tag for the `<rule>` element.  Nested in the `<rule>` element is an other element containing a redacted value, which includes angle brackets in its formatting (but it is not an XML element).  When removed, the XML parses normally and no longer needs `<wrapper>` elements.

These redacted values are very common in the XML I'm working in.  If I can't parse the XML bacause of them, how can I systematically replace/remove them (I don't need them)?  The redacted values look like this in the XML:

```
<argument>
 <value>
  <PII:H101(n5tSfjvfgkgVvZ2scBE9fdv2ui7O4A74R0OvGkR208Y=)>@gmail.com</value>
</argument>
```

Comment: If it is stored as a string, try replacing all the double quote with single quote (" to '). I've tested it without the "wrapper" and it works fine.

Comment: @WesH I can't reproduce the problem either, see the demo : https://dotnetfiddle.net/w1rWdJ

Comment: I dug a bit further and believe I've found the root cause: a redacted value further down contains angle brackets, which seems to be causing the error.  I'm not sure how to remove these values though, if I can't parse the XML to begin with.  I updated the question and title to match.

Answer (score 0):

The following code was tested and works fine.
Your problem might be in the double quotes if it is stored as a string.

If your problem persist you must supply us more information regarding how you pull this XML to a string.

```
string xml = "<rule name='U.S. Financial: PCI'>  <keyValues>    <keyValue key='id' value='3421c776-c95f-4ed2-915b-a684b97ae06b' />    <keyValue key='minCount' value='1' />  </keyValues></rule>";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse( xml);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make input string readable I use this format

```
string xml =
                "<rule name=\"U.S. Financial: PCI\">" +
                  "<keyValues>" +
                    "<keyValue key=\"id\" value=\"3421c776-c95f-4ed2-915b-a684b97ae06b\" />" +
                    "<keyValue key=\"minCount\" value=\"1\" />" +
                  "</keyValues>" +
                "</rule>";
```